# How to set onclick="false" in a framelayout?

Tags: java, android

I have a frameLayout that include Imageviews inside,
this is the xml:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/inquiries_treatmentImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mycontactings12"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/newsImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/newsanduupdate"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/createReportImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"

            android:background="@drawable/createreport"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"

            android:clickable="false"
            android:background="@color/orange" />



</FrameLayout>
```

the 3 imageViews have onClick function,
I want that when the user is clicked on the fourth  imageView, the third's Onclick fucction doesn't clicked,

the imageViews need to be like this:

someone have some way to do it?
[image]

thank you!

Comment: Sorry, your question is a little unclear. So, do you want to disable the click on third imageview when user clicks on the fourth imageview?

Comment: Your views are overlapping, that's why when you click one, the other's clicked.

Comment: There are a few methods out there that they can do the work for you. Like `setEnabled(false)` or `setClickable(false)` or `android:enabled="false"` . It depends on what you want exactly and how you want to do it.

Comment: wanted thank you for your answer, yes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your image views are all overlapped.

Try this:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/inquiries_treatmentImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mycontactings12"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/newsImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/newsanduupdate"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/createReportImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"

            android:background="@drawable/createreport"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:background="@color/orange" />
```

Hope this is what you need.

**Edited**

Okay I think I found the work around

Set onTouch() listener for your last imageView and consume it.

In your onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Your codes ...

    ImageView imageViewEmpty = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.empty);
    imageViewEmpty.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              return true; // Consume the event!
         }
    });
}
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: your answer mean that I need to remove the framelayout?

Comment: No, keep the framelayout.

Comment: so what are the changes that you made? it's look like my code?

Comment: I set all image height to `android:layout_height="100dp"` to prevent overlapping.

Comment: Have you try with it and see if your problem still occur?

Comment: ok but I nedd that one image will cover the end of the second image so your change is destroes this. I'm trying a lot of time to add some screenshot but nothing, do you know how to add it to my question?

Comment: nothing... what the   <requestFocus></requestFocus> need to do? I added it but it's not work :(

Comment: Yes, I have tried the codes. What is the error about? Check your log.

Comment: No prob dude. Happy coding~